# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelected' of undefined (Chrome-Extension )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi i am making google chrome extension and stucked with error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelected' of undefined
```

My code is below

called function  getQueryString(); inside if statement is creating error

key_event.js

```
if (window == top) {
window.addEventListener('keyup', doKeyPress, false); //add the keyboard handler

}
  trigger_key = 37; 
     function doKeyPress(e){
     if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 37)
     { 
            alert("leftpressed");
            getQueryString();
    }
    else if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 39){ // if e.shiftKey is not provided then script will run at all instances of typing "G"
         alert("rightpressed");

        getQueryString();
    }
    }

    function getParameterByName(name,urlPara) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(urlPara);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

 function getQueryString() {
          chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
          var tab = tab.url;
          var queryString = {};
          var substr = tab.replace(
          new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
          function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
      );  
      var current = getParameterByName('page',tab);
         var reExp = 'page=' + current;
         current = parseInt(current, 10)-1;
        var newUrl = tab.replace(reExp, 'page=' + current);
        console.log(newUrl);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: newUrl});
    });
}
```

help can bring cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script `key_event.js` is a content script. It is running in the context of the website rather than the extension context. As a result it cannot use all of the `chrome` API (like `chrome.tabs`).

In order to get the current website URL from inside the website context, you can use `window.location.href`. You can also get the query string using `window.location.search`. So no need to query `chrome.tabs` here.

Something in the lines of

```
var tabURL = window.location.href;
var queryString = window.location.search;
```

Comment: where does popup.html come from? Are we talking about the same extension, because there is no popup.html in your manifest mentioned above. Your question is about an error in the content script, so there should be no popup.html involved

Comment: When using "window.location.href" i get the path of the extension:"CHROME-EXTENSION://" - Why is that?